# Display meeting in CalendarView - Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, calendar

i am new to Windows 10 UWP-Apps and try to create a calendar app.
On my page, the user can create a meeting. Here i have two textboxes for titel and location and a datepicker.
With the (speichern-)safe-button you can save the meeting.

Now my question is, is there any possibility to see the meeting in the CalendarView? I try to figure out, how the day in CalendarView gets a point-symbol by creating a meeting. And if the user click on this day, he can see the meeting-information.

```
private void btnSpeichern_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TerminAnlegen();
    showDialog("Termin wurde hinzugefügt.");
}
```

```
public async void TerminAnlegen()
{
    StorageFolder Ordner = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile Datendatei = await Ordner.CreateFileAsync("kalender.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    string Daten = tbTitel.Text + ", " + tbOrt.Text + ", " + datePicker.Date;
    if(Daten != "")
    {
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(Datendatei, Daten);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!
Sarah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [written a blogpost](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/02/customizing-day-numbers-in-uwp-calendarview/) which could be helpful to understand how the `CalendarView` generates individual days.

In your case, you will need to subscribe to the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event and wait for it to be executed for the date you are looking for. The `CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs` contains an `Item` property of type `CalendarViewDayItem`, which in turn has a [`Date` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem.date?view=winrt-19041), which you can check.

Once you have the `CalendarViewDayItem` you want to adjust, you can access its visual tree  (you can use `VisualTreeHelper` methods) and add your own child in it. You can also set a custom `ControlTemplate` to render custom content on top of the "date".

Note - if you need to add the customization after the `CalendarView` dates were already rendered, you can do so as well by searching for `CalendarViewDayItem` types in the `CalendarView`'s visual tree.

You may find the [Visual Tree Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree) from Windows Community Toolkit useful :-) .

### Full example

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DatePicker x:Name="Picker" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add</Button>
    <CalendarView CalendarViewDayItemChanging="Calendar_CalendarViewDayItemChanging" x:Name="Calendar" />
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<DateTimeOffset> _highlightedDates = new List<DateTimeOffset>();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _highlightedDates.Add(Picker.Date.Date);
        UpdateCalendar();
    }

    private void UpdateCalendar()
    {
        var displayedDays = Calendar.FindDescendants<CalendarViewDayItem>();
        foreach (var displayedDay in displayedDays)
        {
            if (_highlightedDates.Contains(displayedDay.Date.Date))
            {
                //highlight
                displayedDay.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Calendar_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_highlightedDates.Contains(args.Item.Date))
        {
            //highlight
            args.Item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation example]

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you very much for your answer. I tried my best but cant figure out how i solve my problem... i have a DatePicker where i can pick a date for my meeting. And i have a CalenderView. I want to change the colour of the day in CalenderView, when i am picking a Date in DatePicker. I hope you can help me... :(

Comment: @Sarah04 I have updated my answer with a full example as well as animation of the result :-)

Comment: hi martin, thank you for your answer. Did you write the "FindDescendants" Definition or did you import it with a using...
Thank you!

Comment: and what are you add with "     _highlightedDates.Add(Picker.Date.Date);" ? :)

Comment: This is just for illustration - I am adding to this `List` the dates I want to highlight. That is not necessarily what you need to write yourself :-) . The `FindDescendants` extension method comes from the Windows Community Toolkit - you can import the namespace -  `using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions`